# How to log ng command output in proper format?

Tags: windows, npm, angular-cli

I am trying to log output for the following commands `ng build -prod > build.log` and `ng test > test.log`. But the content in log files is partially unreadable format.

```
[33m29 01 2018 08:16:38.574:WARN [karma]: [39mNo captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
[32m29 01 2018 08:16:38.668:INFO [karma]: [39mKarma v1.4.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
[32m29 01 2018 08:16:38.669:INFO [launcher]: [39mLaunching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
[32m29 01 2018 08:16:38.690:INFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser Chrome
```

When I open it in notepad++ I am seeing some [ESC] character as well.

How can we change the output format of `ng` command or properly log the output?
I tried to run the commands from cmd prompt and powershell. The result is same.

Answer (score 0):

Those are console escape sequences that are meant to be interpreted by a console.
The ones in the output you provided are meant to colorize the Karma output.
In order to disable them you could set `colors: false` in the karma.conf file.
See http://karma-runner.github.io/3.0/config/configuration-file.html search for colors section.